# Is $\Lambda(T^{*}E)=\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\Lambda^k(T^{*}E)$ a complex line bundle over $T^{*}E$?

Tags: vector-bundles, exterior-algebra, direct-sum

Is $\Lambda(T^{*}E)=\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\Lambda^k(T^{*}E)$ a complex line bundle over $T^{*}E$? I know that $\Lambda(T^{*}E)=\bigoplus\Lambda^k(T^{*}E)=\Lambda^0(T^{*}E)\oplus\cdots\oplus\Lambda^n(T^{*}E)$. Since $\Lambda^n(T^{*}E)$ is a line bundle over $T^{*}E$, I guess my question can be stated in a more general way: *if $A_1\oplus\cdots\oplus A_n$ is a direct sum of algebras, such that $A_n$ is a line bundle over $X$, then is $A_1\oplus\cdots\oplus A_n$ a line bundle over $X$?*

Comment: Two comments.  First, $\Lambda^k(T^*E)$ is a priori only a vector bundle over $E$.  Second, a direct sum of line bundles will not be a line bundle but rather a higher rank vector bundle.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion in your question. Are you sure that is what you mean to ask? As I understand it, the answer is trivially _no_. A vector bundle that decomposes as a direct sum of vector bundles has dimension equal to the sum of the dimensions of the vector bundles that appear in the sum...

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I understand - how could I have been so foolish? So, in conclusion, $\Lambda^k(T^{*}E)$ is **not** a line bundle over $T^{*}(E).$ Thanks!

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I understand - I made a foolish mistake. Please see my comment above.

Comment: Usually you'd include the 0-th exterior power $\Lambda^0(T^*E)$ (which is a line bundle) in the definition of $\Lambda(T^*E)$; in any case, $\Lambda(T^*E)$ (with the correct definition) is a vector bundle of dimension $2^n$ over $E$ (not $T^*E$) where, I take it, $E$ is a manifold of (real) dimension $n$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thanks a lot for your help. I understand that $\Lambda(T^{*}E)$ is **not** a line bundle over $T^{*}(E)$.

Comment: It's not a vector bundle over $T^*E$! It's a vector bundle over $E$!!!

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Yes, that's exactly what I've conveyed in my comment.